# Create a query SELECT and then INSERT from found results

Tags: mysql

and I am trying to create an INSERT query into database according to results of a SELECT query so I can register 500 users of our website(using their emails).
This is my SELECT query which gets the user IDS of the users by inputting the emails:

```
SELECT 'ID' 
FROM `wpfe_users` 
WHERE `user_email` LIKE 'email2@bd.com' OR `user_email` LIKE 'email2@bd.com' or ETC...
```

The INSERT query is this one:

```
INSERT INTO `pool_wpfe_pool_users` (`user_id`, `pool_id`) 
VALUES ('905', '5379') , ('906', '5379') , ETC...
```

So basically I want to know how to write a query that can have both and the most efficient way to add the 500 emails. Thank you.

Comment: Where does `pool_id` come from?

Comment: does the documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO pool_wpfe_pool_users (user_id, pool_id) 
SELECT ID,'xxxx' FROM wpfe_users WHERE user_email LIKE 'email2@bd.com' OR 
user_email LIKE 'email2@bd.com'
```

for pool_id i have put 'xxxx'  i think u can figure that one out.